# Source spreadsheet changes links in destination spreadsheet from .xlsx to .txt when saving source as text

Tags: hyperlink

I am a photographer. I use Photoshop to process data from an Excel spreadsheet. Photoshop requires that the data be imported from a .txt or .csv file.

My source spreadsheet is in .xlsx format which links to a couple of destination spreadsheets.

However, before I can use the data from the spreadsheet in Photoshop, I have to save it as a MS-DOS text file. In doing so, all the links from the destination .xlsx spreadsheet change from .xlsx to .txt. As a result, the destination spreadsheet will not update because it now gets its updates from a .txt file rather than a .xlsx file. The same is true if I save the .xlsx file as a .csv file.

I can “fix” this by going to Data>Edit Links>Change Source and set the source back to the .xlsx spreadsheet. After that, everything is Hunky Dory. But, because I’m lazy and sometimes forget, I would rather my spreadsheet not change the links from .xlsx to .txt when I save it as a .txt file for use in Photoshop.

Example: ='[_TEST-CoA-Placards.**xlsx**]Sheet1'!$J$3 changes to ='[_TEST-CoA-Placards.**txt**]Sheet1'!$J$3' in the destination spreadsheet after saving the source spreadsheet to text.

Is there a solution?

Thank you for your help.

No matter what format I use to export the source spreadsheet, it changes the link to that of the saved spreadsheet; .txt, csv, etc.